# Air bubbles in boiling tea?

Tags: thermodynamics, water, air

I read a few topics about forming air bubbles in boiling water,for exemple:tea.

See: http://apho2011.tau.ac.il/.upload/APhO2008_theory_prob1.pdf

Water is formed by hydrogen and oxygen.
*How can **air** bubbles be formed just from hydrogen and oxygen*,taking into account the composition of air :78.09% nitrogen, 20.95% oxygen, 0.93% argon, 0.04% carbon dioxide?

Comment: There is always dissolved air in water.

Comment: So,how can all the disolved air molecules combine in the perfect composition to make air bubble?

Comment: They do not. The air inside the air bubble will have water vapour in it exerting a vapour pressure characteristic of the temperature of the water.